# How to reinstall SSISDB

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, ssis

I have a SQL Server 2014 Enterprise Edition where the SSISDB catalog is already here, but corrupted because of a rogue package that made it balloon to enormous size and a failed cleanup attempt.

Is there any way to create the SSISDB catalog anew?